# Any way to tweak Chrome Dev Tools highlight color?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Chrome Dev Tools on a Mac ... and it's nearly impossible to see which text is highlighted (selected) when I'm editing.

See below ... the word 'selected' is selected – you can barely see the slight blue tint.

How can I tweak this color? I do NOT want to switch to Light mode.

[image]

All solutions I've found here from the past have been deprecated.

Comment: Looks like a bug in devtools. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary. A workaround may be to install a *devtools theme extension*.